# AWS Amplify Performance Boost with NextJS 12 - Unexpected Backend Environment Switch

Tags: next.js, backend, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I recently accepted a "performance improvement" on AWS Amplify while working with Nextjs 12. The installation was successful, and everything seemed to go well initially.

However, I soon noticed an unexpected issue. After the performance improvement, Amplify linked everything to my dev backend environment, affecting both environment variables and my Cognito User Pool. Interestingly, I didn't make any changes that would prompt this behavior.

In an attempt to troubleshoot the problem, I've tried multiple tests and redeployments, but unfortunately, nothing seems to rectify the issue.

Furthermore, I've also tried pulling the dev and main backend locally using amplify pull and then pushing again with amplify push. Still, the problem persists.

I'm currently stuck, as it seems nothing I do changes the situation. Has anyone else faced a similar issue, or does anyone have any insights into what might be causing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: redeploy frontend and backend in a new amplify app
with riassociating the previous resources (auth, storage...)

```
amplify import auth
amplify import storage
...
```